# Firebase cloud function fluent-ffmpeg resize and convert

Tags: firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, mp4, fluent-ffmpeg

In the firebase cloud functions I upload a video in `.webm` format, I want to resize it and convert it to `.mp4`.
I am able to generate a file, and reupload the generated file to the firebase storage bucket.

Problem is: the file is unreadable.
How can I assess the file integrity and attributes before and after conversion?

this is the code of my firebase cloud function:

```
/**
 * When a video is uploaded in the Storage bucket,
 * generate a resizing and if it's a webm file convert in mp4.
 */

export const resizeVideo = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  console.log(`Processing file: ${object.name}`);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), object.name + "");
  const resizedTempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "resized_" + object.name?.replace("webm", "mp4"));
  if (object.name?.includes("resized_")) {
    console.log("Already resized");
    return false;
  }
  return new Promise(()=>{
    ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
    .format("mp4")
    .toFormat("mp4")
    .size("1920x1080")
    .videoCodec("libx264")
    .audioCodec("aac")
    .audioBitrate("128k")
    .audioChannels(2)
    .withAudioBitrate("128k")
    .withAudioChannels(2)
    .withAudioCodec("aac")
    .withVideoCodec("libx264")
    .withVideoBitrate("1000k")
    .withSize("1920x1080")
    .outputOptions([
      '-c:v libx264',
      '-c:a aac',
      '-pix_fmt yuv420p',
      '-profile:v main',
      '-level 3.1',
      '-movflags +faststart',
      '-max_muxing_queue_size 9999',
    ])
    .output(resizedTempFilePath)
    .save(resizedTempFilePath)
    .on("error", function(err: { message: any; }, stdout: any, stderr: any) {
      console.log("Error on resize ", err.message);
      console.log("stdout ", stdout);
      console.log("stderr ", stderr);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      console.log("Finished resizing! ", resizedTempFilePath);
      fs.readdirSync(os.tmpdir()).forEach((file) =>{
        if (file === ("resized_" + object.name?.replace("webm", "mp4"))){
          console.log(`${resizedTempFilePath} created!`);
          admin.storage().bucket().upload(path.join(os.tmpdir(), "resized_" + object.name), {
            destination: "resized_" + object.name?.replace("webm", "mp4"),
            metadata: {
              contentType: "video/mp4",
            },
          }).then(() => {
            console.log(`Uploaded ${resizedTempFilePath}`);
          }
          ).catch((err) => {
            console.log(`Error on upload ${resizedTempFilePath}`, err);
          }
          );
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try using using a different ffmpeg library. [Check out the documentation for node-ffmpeg on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg).